# How to apply show and hide on button click?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I wanted to perform show and hide on my button click. I have the following code. I want to show or apply my css style(`color:red`) on my "`maindiv`" content on clicking of button "`Click`".
        Again, if I click that `Click` button then it should hide or display it's normal content like earlier(i.e without any css style of red), like this it should come.

```
Getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/ffKTy/537/).

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="maindiv">
    <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
       <div id="mainContainer">
          <div id="testId">
              <button type="button"  ng-click="testExpand()">Click</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.testExpand = function(){
            alert("testExpand is called to show");
            document.querySelector("maindiv").classList.add("maindivColor");
        } 
}]);
```

Comment: use `ng-style` or `ng-class` directive

Comment: @Hadi, how can I apply ng-show or ng-hide on my div ? I have tried, but i am not getting exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#`

```
document.querySelector("#maindiv").classList.toggle("maindivColor");
```

And use `toggle` instead of `add`

Comment: @Vuk Stanković, yes. Perfect ! Thanks.

Comment: @Dhanam You should use angularjs rather than manipulating DOM directly

Comment: I agree. Angular loses point to some extent if you manipulate DOM outside of it. Still I just wanted to point out errors in particular code posted in original question

Answer (score 2):

Try angularjs way.

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {        
$scope.testExpand = function(){
   //alert("testExpand is called to show");
   $scope.applyCss = !$scope.applyCss;      
  }
         }]);
```

```css
.maindivColor {
  color:red;
}

.mainContainer {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

#testId {
//  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-class="{'maindivColor':applyCss}"><p>Normal Content</p></div>
    <div ng-show="applyCss" ng-class="{'maindivColor':applyCss}">
    <p>
    Test Content
    </p>
    </div>
       <div>
         
              <button type="button"  ng-click="testExpand()">Click</button>
          
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('surveyController', function($scope){
      $scope.backgroundColor = 'yellow';


      $scope.changeStyle = function(){
        if ($scope.backgroundColor == 'red') {
          $scope.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }else{
          $scope.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
      }


    });


  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="surveyController" ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="maindiv" ng-style="{background: backgroundColor}">
    <p>Test Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContainer">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="changeStyle()">Change Style</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular way to dynamically add CSS class, It can be achieved using  [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

> The `ngClass` directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

```
<div id="maindiv" ng-class="{'maindivColor' : hideMainDiv }">
```

*Controller*

```
$scope.testExpand = function(){
    alert("testExpand is called to show");
    $scope.hideMainDiv = !$scope.hideMainDiv;
}
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.testExpand = function() {
    console.log("testExpand is called to hide");
    $scope.hideMainDiv = !$scope.hideMainDiv;
  }
}]);
```

```css
.maindivColor {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="maindiv" ng-class="{'maindivColor' : hideMainDiv }">
      <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="testId">
        <button type="button" ng-click="testExpand()">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
  $scope.testExpand = function(){
   alert("testExpand is called to show");
      var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#maindiv' ) );
       
     if(myEl.hasClass('maindivColor')){
  
     myEl.removeClass('maindivColor');
    
    }else{
    myEl.addClass('maindivColor');
    }
   
  
  }
  
  
}]);
```

```css
.maindivColor {
  color:red;
}

.mainContainer {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

#testId {
//  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="maindiv">
    <p>
    Test Content
    </p>
    </div>
       <div id="mainContainer">
          <div id="testId">
              <button type="button"  ng-click="testExpand()">Click</button>
          </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best advice here: use angular things to do job in angular. 
The faster you become 'ok' with this, the better.
You can add a 'style' variable in the controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.style = {};
      $scope.testExpand = function(){
            alert("testExpand is called to show");
            if ($scope.style.color)
                $scope.style.color = red;
            else delete $scope.style.color;
        } 
}]);
```

And then you simple modify your html this way:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-style="style">
    <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
       <div id="mainContainer">
          <div id="testId">
              <button type="button" ng-click="testExpand()">Click</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery in the following way.

```
$(document).find('.yourButton').hide();
```

Comment: it should be a comment, and he want with angular not JQUERY :(]